# How to read file into NSSrting without encoding?

Tags: cocoa, text, encoding, nsstring

I've some text files with accented characters, but I do not know the encoding, and I want the text to be displayed as-is in a NSTextField.

I can use [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:] but this method is deprecated.  All the other methods require the user to supply the text encoding.  I don't want to use any methods that would try to guess at the encoding, because: 1. they won't work all the times, 2. I really just want to display the contents of the file the way it is in NSTextField.

So what should I do?

Comment: That won't work as it strips out the accents in the text.

Answer (score 2):

> I really just want to display the contents of the file the way it is in NSTextField.

You are asking the impossible, "the way it is" *depends* on the encoding. The file contains a sequence of bytes, which are just strings of eight 0's & 1's. You have to interpret those strings of bits. You can take them four at a time and interpret them as 32 bit integers, or 32 bit floats, or UTF32 – and you'll get a different result each time. Or you can take them one at a time and interpret them as ASCII, UTF, EBCDIC, etc, etc, etc – and you'll get different results.

The closest you get to "the way it is" is to dump the bytes in binary, octal or hex – i.e. what the `od` command line command will do for you. You can try to figure it out, e.g. as the `file` command does, or you need to know. (See also [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/151972/determining-the-encoding-of-a-file-on-mac-os-x).)

Comment: The text file I'm trying to read is a SRT subtitle file.  It may contain something like this:
"
1
00:03:45,589 --> 00:03:48,822
Serve aiuto! C'Ë nessuno?
"
Since I don't know the encoding of the SRT text, how can I possibly read it with a specific char encoding?  The deprecated method allows me to read the original text file as-is into the NSString

Comment: If I follow what you're dong your approach is wrong, see your [related qestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38940571/how-to-display-accented-characters-using-nsmutableattributedstring)

Comment: BRW the deprecated method, `stringWithContentsOfFile:`, did not allow you to read the as-is; rather it interpreted the contents of the file by determing the encoding or using a default one - check its [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithContentsOfFile:)

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using:

```
[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding] error:nil]
```

This gives me the same result as `[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:]`

Comment: you are contradicting yourself with this answer.. you dont want to 'guess' but thats what you do now ;) -- the methods to propertly guess work better than your 'assuming' too

Comment: Eventually, I tried using UTF8 first then defaultCStringEncoding.  This seems to work for the intent and purpose of what I'm doing.  Which is the same result I got from `[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:]`