# How to display accented characters using NSMutableAttributedString?

Tags: html, cocoa, encoding, nsstring

In my `NSString`, I've some accented characters and html tags, such as `<i></i>`. I want to display them in `NSTextField` with text attributes to them.

When I build the attrStr, I use:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:[text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                   options:@{NSWebPreferencesDocumentOption : webPreferences}
                                                        documentAttributes:NULL];
```

I display the text as follow:

```
someTextField.attributedStringValue = attrStr;
```

But this require I know the encoding of the `NSString`, but the problem is that I do not know the encoding.  So how do I build an attribute string without knowing the encoding?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know the encoding of your `NSString` – it is an Objective-C string. The definition of `dataUsingEncoding:` states, emphasis added:

> Returns an `NSData` object containing a representation of the receiver *encoded using a given encoding*.

This method converts from whatever encoding `NSString` uses internally *into* the specified encoding – so the result is your case is an `NSData` containing the bytes of a UTF8 string.

If you are seeing invalid results maybe the issue is when you create the original `NSString`?

HTH

**Addendum** I now see you asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939780/how-to-read-file-into-nssting-without-encoding) first (I added an answer – basically you need to know or guess). Why are you reading the file into an `NSString` in the first place? Just read it directly into an `NSData` and then let the HTML parser sort it out (it will either read the HTML encoding tag or default to an encoding).

Comment: Well, it is not all that simple.  If I read it in as NSData, I cannot parse NSData to extract the subtitle strings in the specific time range.  But in order to read the file in as string, I need to know the encoding, something I've no idea about.  Maybe I need to look at the source code of VLC to see how they do this.  VLC seems to decode the subtitle correctly, regardless of the encoding used in the subtitle text.

Comment: A brief DuckDuckGo suggests The encoding of SRT files is not defined, VLC describes it as "informally Unicode" but as you suggest it's source might help you as it appears it can handle (some?) non-Unicode files. Time for you do to some research. Good hunting!

Comment: As it turns out, VLC does not decode everything correctly, but the Mac Blu-Ray Player does.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I found that if I use `NSUnicodeStringEncoding` on the above, the accented chars will be displayed correctly.